# How to Get Date Object with formatted date from my EditText (Stored through Spinner)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got a formatted date through my EditText using a Spinner popup (onClicking the EditText). How do i stored the formatted date as a Date object for storing into the database. Below are the code Sample

```
Context context = this;
Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String dateFormat = "dd / MM / yyyy";
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.UK);

private EditText mDOB = findViewById(R.id.date_of_birth);
private Date dateOfBirth;


 private void datePicker() {

    // init - set date to current date
    long currentdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String dateString = sdf.format(currentdate);
    mDOB.setHint(dateString);

    // set calendar date and update editDate
    date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateDate();
        }

    };

// onclick - popup datepicker
    mDOB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(context, date, myCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });
}

private void updateDate() {
    mDOB.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    dateOfBirth = mDOB.???
}
```

Comment: `myCalendar.getTime()` returns `Date`, why not just `dateOfBirth = myCalendar.getTime()`?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Nice... i find this very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values.

So you will not store *date as a Date*.  
Format the date as you like and store it say as `TEXT`  or   
store `myCalendar.getTime()` as `INTEGER`.